# How to get more efficiency out of 555 timer + MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, 555, delay

I needed to build a delay circuit so I'm following this guide:
http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/555-timer-delay-before-turn-on-circuit.php

[image: schematic]

Using this circuit, I get a delay of about 5 seconds before the LED turns on.
The only big difference is the output of the 555 is going into the gate of a [IRFZ44N MOSFET](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3575220b) as I needed more power.

The MOSFET source is hooked to ground, and the drain is hooked to a 330 Ohm resistor -> LED -> 5V.

However, with 5V input voltage, I can only get 3V across the drain and source.
How could I improve this circuit to give me more efficiency, closer to my 5V?

EDIT:
I'm following the schematic from the guide. It's exhibiting the same behavior as the guide, so the timing circuit should be correct. The only difference is the MOSFET. I also added a 330 Ohm resistor between the 555 pin 3 output and MOSFET gate and now I'm getting full voltage from drain.  Looks like the gate was leeching some voltage.

Comment: Here is a comment, replace the word "here" with "you", replace "is" with "should make" and replace "a comment" with "a proper schematic".

Comment: Well, this is a pretty simple circuit. Most of the schematic is there. In the meanwhile, I think I solved the issue by moving the resistor between the 555 and gate. I'm getting the full 5V. Closing this.

Comment: It would be nice if you add a schematic instead of a snap of the breadboard connection!

Comment: Yes, the snap was a bad idea.

Comment: I don't see any MOSFET in that schematic.

Comment: If you read above, the schematic is from the website. The only "difference" is the MOSFET. I noted how I hooked up the MOSFET above. But the issue is resolved now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vgs(th) is when it barely conducts at Vgs=2~4V so you need 2.5x to 4x this value minimum RdsOn for low Vds at high current.

Since Vout is Bipolar it is not rail to rail.  So either use a sub-threshold FET or V=+12